# NullReferenceException from JsonSerializer in POST method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to write a simple REST API in #C, but I ran into a problem with a rather unhelpful error message very early when writing a POST handler. I'm using .NET Core 3.0 and the project was created with the ASP.NET Core API template in Visual Studio.

This is a simplified version of my code that still triggers the issue (the classes are in separate Files in the full project):

```
[Route("api/blub")]
[ApiController]
public class BlubController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Blub> Get()
    {
        return new Blub[0];
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Blub> PostBlub([FromBody] string[] paths)
    {
        return new Blub(paths);
    }
}

public class Blub
{
    public Blub(string[] paths)
    {
        this.Paths = paths;
        StartedAt = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public string[] Paths { get; }
    public DateTime StartedAt { get; }
}
```

The payload of my POST request is something like the following:

```
{ "paths": [ "abc", "def" ] }
```

I'm getting the following Exception when performing a POST request to my `api/blub` route:

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.HandleStartObject(JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& state)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonSerializerOptions options, Utf8JsonReader& reader, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore(JsonReaderState& readerState, Boolean isFinalBlock, ReadOnlySpan`1 buffer, JsonSerializerOptions options, ReadStack& readStack)
   at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadAsync[TValue](Stream utf8Json, Type returnType, JsonSerializerOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerBinderDelegateProvider.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<CreateBinderDelegate>g__Bind|0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

It doesn't matter whether my POST request contains the correct body or not, any POST requests seems to trigger this exception. The GET request works without issues. I tried to log to the console and set a breakpoint in my function, but as far as I can tell the exception is thrown even before my function is called.

Why is the JsonFormatter throwing an exception here, and how can I fix this?

Comment: What's the payload you are sending in POST request?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya  I tried different ones and it didn't matter, I always got the exception. The intended payload is something like `{
 "paths": [
  "abc",
  "def"
 ]
}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an issue in type mapping, either change method signature to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult<Blub> PostBlub([FromBody] MyRequest request)
{
    return new Blub(request.Paths);
}

public class MyRequest
{
    public string[] Paths { get; set; }
}
```

Or change the payload to:

```
 [ "abc", "def" ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that fixes the issue. I'll have to read up on the mapping more, it's clear I misunderstood it. But I'm a bit confused that it throws an exception, as the documentation seemed to indicate that it would typically not do that even if the parameter can't be matched.

Comment: @MadScientist agree, and usually it works this way, when you talking about classes, but seems like arrays are different. Plus they changes JSON implementation in .NET Core 3, if you would try you code in 2.2 it will give you clear exception message

Answer (score 0):

> This simply means that some `member/variable` of some reference type
>   is dereferenced by using and of its instance `non-static` members,
>   which requires this `member/variable` to be `non-null`, but in fact it
>   appears to be `null`. Simply if it execute it under debugger, it will
>   stop the execution where the exception is thrown. Put a break point on
>   that line, restart the application and come to this point again.
>   Evaluate all references involved in next line and see which one is
>   null while it needs to be not null. After you figure this out, fix the
>   code: either make sure the member/variable is properly initialized to
>   a `non-null` reference, or check it for `null` and, in case of `null`,
>   do something else.

**Use the below code snippet:**

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Blub> PostBlub([FromBody] APIRequest request)
    {
        return new Blub(request.Paths);
    }

    public class APIRequest
    {
        public string[] Paths { get; set; }
    }
```